# How do I install libsandbox? I have some problems during installation

Tags: python, linux, sandbox, python-c-extension, pysandbox

I have some problems installing [libsandbox](http://openjudge.net/~liuyu/Project/LibSandbox) and pysandbox. I've tried with binary and source packages but no. It seems to do OK but, when I run:

```
from sandbox import *
```

it displays

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sandbox/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
from . import _sandbox
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sandbox/_sandbox.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

How can I make it work? I'm running on Linux 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have installed 32bit pysandbox on a 64bit machine, and trying to import the 32bit module from a 64bit python interpreter.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of `libsandbox`.